# Using JQuery to hide and show text

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

I want to use JQuery to hide text when web page is launched and when you click on an item it will show the hidden text.

When I load the page it shows the text in h2 and the text in h3 and hides the text in ptdeats as expected. When I click on the text containing "Jason O'Reilly", it doesn't show the text "Hi there, my name is Jay......".

The classes trainers ptpics, pt, center are configured in css.

The jquery is also configured to highlight h3 and also when h3 is click it shows the text and when you click on h3 it hides it again.

This is what I have configured in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="trainersptjavascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="trainers">
            <h2 class="center">Choose your Personal Trainer</h2>
            <div class="ptpics center">
                <h3 class="pt center">Jason O'Reilly</h3>
                <p class="center"><img src="images/ptjay.jpg" alt="Westside Fitness PT Jason" width="320" height="350"></p>
                <p class="ptdeats">Hi there , my name is Jay I am a personal trainer.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ptpics center">
                <h3 class="pt center">Jean Meehan</h3>
                <p class="center"><img src="images/ptjean.jpg" alt="Westside Fitness PT Jean" width="320" height="350"></p>
                <p class="ptdeats">I am a qualified Level 4 Personal Trainer.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ptpics center">
                <h3 class="pt center">Aoife McIntyre</h3>
                <p class="center"><img src="images/ptaoife.jpg" alt="Westside Fitness PT Aoifendrew" width="320" height="350"></p>
                <p class="ptdeats">I am Registered Nurse with a Personal Training Qualification.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the css configuration

```
.trainers
    {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #36454F;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: justify;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    float: left;
    }

.pt
    {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    float: left;
    }

.ptpics
    {
    width: 33%;
    background-color: #36454F;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px;
    border-color:#009900;
    text-align: justify;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    }
```

JQuery configuration:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".me").hide();
$(".pt").click(function(){
$(".me").show();
});
});
```

Comment: It is actually displayed right after your image! Check the snippet in the question!

Comment: I tested your code it showed the value 'Hi there', does any error message appear to you?

Comment: I am using IE, when the page loads, IE reports that "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or Active X controls. I then click on "Allow Blocked Content". This then hides the text "Hi there". This is as expected. When I click on the h3 text "My Name", it doesn't show the "Hi there" text.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with which element the event is triggering on. try:

```
$(".ptpic").click(function(){
$(".me").show();
});
```

If that works, then you might not be clicking in the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. I tested it out, and it did work.

Make sure you close the html tabs:

```
<div class="ptpic center">
<h3 class="pt center">My Name</h3>
<p class="center"><img src="images/me.jpg" alt="Me" width="320" height="350"></p>
<p class="me">Hi there</p>
```

Make sure you click on the actual text that says "My Name" because if you just click close to it, it might not exactly work. A good way to test it out is to put a background color on the target object (here it's either `h3` or `.pt`) via CSS. Then, clicking anywhere inside that box should be okay!

If you instead wanted the text to toggle hide and show, then do this into your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".me").hide();
    $(".pt").click(function(){
        $(".me").toggle();
    });
});
```

This will alternate between show and hide every time you chick on the `.pt` block.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I am definitely hitting on the right spot, 100%.

Comment: Hey, I tried this, not working, would it be due to the class in css

Comment: Did you try using a different browser? Try Chrome and let me know if that works

Comment: I have tried Firefox and Chrome and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Check my other answer [above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43154051/7452002). That one should work because it's a copy paste. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I copied and pasted your code and made a few changes! These changes should fix them. Let me know if they work.

HTML:

```
<!--Here I ONLY added the id's into each h3 elements. They should not cause any damage to the code. I will tell you why at the end. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="trainersptjavascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="trainers">
            <h2 class="center">Choose your Personal Trainer</h2>
            <div class="ptpics center">
                <h3 class="pt center" id="h3_1">Jason O'Reilly</h3>
                <p class="center"><img src="images/ptjay.jpg" alt="Westside Fitness PT Jason" width="320" height="350"></p>
                <p class="ptdeats">Hi there , my name is Jay I am a personal trainer.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ptpics center">
                <h3 class="pt center" id="h3_2">Jean Meehan</h3>
                <p class="center"><img src="images/ptjean.jpg" alt="Westside Fitness PT Jean" width="320" height="350"></p>
                <p class="ptdeats">I am a qualified Level 4 Personal Trainer.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ptpics center">
                <h3 class="pt center" id="h3_3">Aoife McIntyre</h3>
                <p class="center"><img src="images/ptaoife.jpg" alt="Westside Fitness PT Aoifendrew" width="320" height="350"></p>
                <p class="ptdeats">I am Registered Nurse with a Personal Training Qualification.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
//I simply modified the classes to put what you wanted it to do. I guess this was simply a class issue then? Because everything seems alright except that. 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ptdeats").hide();
    $(".pt").click(function(){
        $(".ptdeats").show();
    });
});
```

JAVASCRIPT, SUGGESTED:

```
//This should work better because you want the user to be able to remove that new added text if they want to. Just a minor suggestion. Toggle makes a hidden object to show and a shown object to hide.
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ptdeats").hide();
    $(".pt").click(function(){
        $(".ptdeats").toggle();
    });
});
```

JAVASCRIPT, ADDUP WITH ID'S, ALSO SUGGESTED:

```
//This is where the ID's come into play. 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ptdeats").hide();
    // console.log(this);
    $(".pt").click(function(){
        $("#"+this.id).next().next().toggle();
    });
});
```

Explanation: The two first Javascript will show all the texts in all ".ptdeats" when you click on ".pt" because you tell JS to show ".ptdeats". Any HTML with that class will show.

Nevertheless, there's a cool trick in JS where you can find any specific attribute of the specific element that you clicked on. Also, if you're unfamiliar with "this", "this" basically designates the elements that you are on. For example, if you click on `<h3 class="pt center" id="h3_1">Jason O'Reilly</h3>`, even though you designated it on JS with ".pt", "this" refers specifically to `<h3 class="pt center" id="h3_1">Jason O'Reilly</h3>`. Try uncommenting the `// console.log(this);` and check your web console to see what I mean.

Finally, `.next()` in jQuery designates the very next element. In here it works only because of how you structured your HTML. The first `.next()` is the `p` tag with the image in it and the second one is the text you actually want to toggle. 
This is better because it will toggle the text specific to the person you are clicking on!

Let me know if this works. I am confident it will: I copied and pasted from what you gave and made only minor changes. I also tested it on four different browsers: Opera, Mozilla, Chrome, and Safari. I don't have IE, so I am not sure how it will behave, but this is nothing too complicated so it should work as expected.

Comment: You can also use `$("#"+this.id).siblings(".ptdeats").toggle();` instead of `$("#"+this.id).next().next().toggle();`. I feel like this `$("#"+this.id).siblings(".ptdeats").toggle();` is safer to use in case you add new sutffs into your HTML.

Comment: Hi, I updated my file and it didn't work. I removed the line <p class="center"><img src="images/ptjay.jpg" alt="Westside Fitness PT Jason"  and it did work. It look like the pic is stopping it from working, should I have something in css to get the information in .ptdeats to load underneath the pic?

Comment: I mean, you could try that. Add an ID to the p block containing the image, remove the image itself, and on CSS, add `#IDOfRespectiveP {min-width: 320px; min-height: 350px; background: url("respectiveImage.jpg") no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;}`. HTML should look like: `<div class="ptpics center"><h3 class="pt center" id="h3_1">Jason O'Reilly</h3><p class="center" id="IDOfRespectiveP"></p><p class="ptdeats">Hi there , my name is Jay I am a personal trainer.</p></div>`. The min-height and min-width ensures the original sizes. However, you lose the "alt" attribute by doing this.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help on this. I got it working by tweaking your code a little bit $(document).ready(function()
 {
 $(".ptdeats").hide();
 $("h3").click(function()
 {
 $("#"+this.id).nextAll(".ptdeats").eq(0).slideToggle(500);
 });